# changing a for loop to a while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was wondering how I could change the following lines of codes to use a `while` loop instead of a `for` loop.

```
for num in range(10):
 print(num+1)
```

It currently prints out the following:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Thanks!

Comment: With a counter and a condition.

Comment: why do you want a while loop instead of a for loop?

Answer (score 2):

```
start = 0
while start != 10:
    start = start + 1
    print(start)
```

hope this hepls

Comment: It might help in this very specific case, but it won't help OP in the future to figure out how to solve their *own* problems.

Answer (score 2):

```
number = 1
while (number <=10):
   print 'The number is:', number
   number = number + 1
```

Comment: This will also print `0` which might not be wanted

Comment: This prints from 0 - 10 OP asked for 1 - 10

Answer (score 1):

The `for` loop runs over an iterable, while a `while` loop runs while a condition is true, so you just need to think of the right condition. 
Here, something counting up to 10 will work:

```
>>> number = 0
>>> while number < 10:
...   print(number + 1)
...   number += 1
...
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Answer (score 1):

Writing code that has the same output is not the same as rewriting code to do the same thing.  Other answers simply do the former, so this solves the latter:

```
numbers = range(10)
while numbers:
  numbers.pop(0) + 1
```

The original code iterates over a list that does not exist outside of the loop - it could work with a list of something other than range(10), but it's not necessarily just a '+ 1' operation.

The conditional statement for a while loop, however, needs to be true for the loop to begin so the list should already exist.  To keep true to the spirit of the original code, we use range() to create the list, and use pop() to iteratively remove the first element from it.

The differences here are that a variable (numbers) gets used, but is empty after the loop, and we don't rely on list comprehension to iterate, but explicitly remove the first element until 'numbers', being empty, results in a false condition.

Answer (score 0):

well..... a while statement operates UNTIL a certain condition is met, as the for operates for a set of given iterations.

in your case you want to print stuff until num reaches 10, so

```
while num <= 10 :
    print num 
    num = num + 1
```

would do

Comment: *until* or *while*?

Comment: You should specify that `num` starts at `1` since OP wants to print 1 to 10.